# Unable to use same @IdClass on parent and child

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue saving a parent object which has a child object. Both objects use @IdClass and refer to the same class (CompositeKey). I am getting the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.test.ClassA was altered from com.test.CompositeKey@1ce60be2 to com.test.CompositeKey@18f9997e
```

Upon debugging I can see that somehow the CompositeKey associated with ClassA is changing to the one associated with ClassB.

I believe that I am saving the objects correctly, and that the issue might be a bug in hibernate somewhere.

If I create two classes (CompsiteKeyA and CompositeKeyB) and have ClassA and ClassB use one each respectively then the error goes away.

Code that triggers the error:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
classA.setName("ClassA name");
classA.setVersion(0);

ClassB classB = new ClassB();
classB.setName("ClassB name");
classB.setVersion(1);
Set<ClassB> classBs = new HashSet<>();
classBs.add(classB);

classA.setClassBs(classBs);

classADao.save(classA);
```

The classB instance is pre-existing in the database, and I expect the pre-existing instance to be associated with the newly saved ClassA instance (via a join table).

Upon debugging the error it can be seen that the CompositeKey instance associated with ClassA has changed from ("ClassA Name", 0) to ("ClassB Name", 1).

DAO (I am using spring data jpa for persistence):

```
public interface ClassADao extends JpaRepository<ClassA, CompositeKey>{}
```

ClassA:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class ClassA extends CompositeKey{
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<ClassB> classBs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ClassB:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class ClassB extends CompositeKey{
    private String otherField;
}
```

CompositeKey:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class CompositeKey {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @Id
    private Integer version;
}
```